# python - open files and other methods for file

Tags: python, file, methods

im trying to code a function `length_n(file_name, n)` where it returns the list of words within `file_name` (a txt file) that has a length of n. `file_name` will be the name of the file containing the list of words. For some reason, when I test my codes, the `open` operation does not successfully open my text file. Does anyone know why? Also, did I use the methods `.read` and `.split` correctly? thank you so much!

```
def length_n(file_name,n):
    #the list of words will be called 
    l1=[]
    #the list of words with the length of n will be called
    l2=[]
    file=open('file_name','r')
    #the individual lines are
    lines=file.read()
    #split the content into words
    l1=lines.split("")
    length=len(l1)
    for i in range (0,length):
        l=len(l1[i])
        if l==n:
            l2.append(l1[i])
            
    return l2
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the "open" operation does not successfully open my text file"? Do you get an error message? If so, what is it?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this:

```
file=open('file_name','r')
```

Python tries to find 'file_name' file, but I'm pretty sure it does not exist.

Here's solution:

```
file=open(f'{file_name}.txt','r') # you can remove '.txt' if you don't need it

#OR

file=open(file_name,'r') # or simply just this
```

Comment: It would be more accurate to start your question explaining that `open('file_name', 'r')` doesn't do what the OP thinks it does or has a typo that they overlooked. It is incorrect to say they can't do it at all.

Comment: Okay, I think I should not have said 'You can't do this', but I have written the explanation below the first code.

Comment: hi, thank you so much for your answer. I tried file=open('{file_name}.txt', 'r,') and tested it with length_n(cool,4) (I have a file named cool.txt in my folder) and it gives the error "no such file or directory: '{file_name}.txt'". It appears that it is taking the file_name as the name of the file hmmm

Comment: @needhelpwithmathandcs, Do not forget the little `f`.

Comment: I also tried file=open(file_name, 'r') and it says: "expected str, bytes, or os.PathLike object, not _io.TextIOWrapper"

Comment: Oh, then convert it string like this: `file_name = str(file_name)`.

Comment: @needhelpwithmathandcs How do you call the `length_n()` function? It looks like the name `file_name` is misleading. Maybe it should be named `file_buffer` instead because you are passing in something that already acts like a file. You don't need to call `open()` at all. Just read from the buffer directly.

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code like that,

```
def length_n(file_name,n):
   #the list of words will be called 
    l1=[]
    #the list of words with the length of n will be called
    l2=[]
    with open(f'{file_name}','r') as file: # We can't use file = because it doesn't read it is a parameter of length_n. Then we should use formatter or file = open(file_name,'r').
          lines=file.read()
          l1=lines.split("")
          length=len(l1)
          for i in range (0,length):
              l=len(l1[i])
              if l==n:
                 l2.append(l1[i])
        
     return l2
```

When we use with open(f'file_name','r') as file it simply close file after your program is close.